# Vtiger CSS Custom Login Issue

Tags: css

Im trying to make my login form in vtiger CRM, editing its Login.tpl file with something like this

[image]

But im finding trouble in vtiger, as you can see here:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: and where is your code?

Comment: here is the code http://codepen.io/joshadamous/pen/yyyqJZ

Comment: using Firefox, works perfectly

Comment: the problem is when its placed in vtiger. check here http://sistema.nubi.media/index.php

Comment: is related to `jquery.ui` overriding some of the CSS

Comment: possible fix to suggest?